# How to infinite scale an svg with jquery?

Tags: jquery, svg

I am trying this but it only works once on the first click while I would expect it to keep scaling on various clicks:

```
$(".map").on("click", function(){
   $(".map svg").css({"-moz-transform": "scale(2.0)", "webkit-transform": "scale(2.0)"});
});
```

Comment: The scaling factor is applied in relation to the original size, not relative. You can easily check that yourself by using your browsers development console and monitoring the computed style tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are still adding a same value :

**Try something like :**

**HTML :**

```
<div class="map" data-scale="0">
   <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(".map").on("click", function(){
    var $map = $(this);
    var $svg = $map.find('svg');
    var current_scale = $map.attr('data-scale');
        current_scale = parseInt(current_scale,10);
    var sclae_to = current_scale + 2;

    $svg.css({'transform': 'scale('+ sclae_to +')'});
    $map.attr('data-scale',sclae_to);
});
```

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/v0fdpczd/

Comment: Thanks a lot, if I reverse the code to scale it down, is there anyway i can fix it not scale any lower than the original size?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the scale value **absolutely**, it doesn't work *relatively*.

After the first click, your element already has the style `transform` set to `scale(2)`, setting the same style again won't change the appearance any more.

Look at this code snippet to see, how it would work *(with a variable storing the current scale value)*:

```js
var zoom_factor = 1;

$(".zoom").click(function(e) {
  // ZOOM IN WITH LEFT MOUSE BUTTON

  zoom_factor *= 1.25;
  
  $(this).css("transform", "scale("+zoom_factor+")");
  return false;
}).bind("contextmenu", function() {
  // ZOOM OUT WITH RIGHT MOUSE BUTTON

  zoom_factor /= 1.25;
  
  $(this).css("transform", "scale("+zoom_factor+")");
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  
  transition:transform .25s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<svg class="zoom" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M17.684,7.925l-5.131-0.67L10.329,2.57c-0.131-0.275-0.527-0.275-0.658,0L7.447,7.255l-5.131,0.67C2.014,7.964,1.892,8.333,2.113,8.54l3.76,3.568L4.924,17.21c-0.056,0.297,0.261,0.525,0.533,0.379L10,15.109l4.543,2.479c0.273,0.153,0.587-0.089,0.533-0.379l-0.949-5.103l3.76-3.568C18.108,8.333,17.986,7.964,17.684,7.925 M13.481,11.723c-0.089,0.083-0.129,0.205-0.105,0.324l0.848,4.547l-4.047-2.208c-0.055-0.03-0.116-0.045-0.176-0.045s-0.122,0.015-0.176,0.045l-4.047,2.208l0.847-4.547c0.023-0.119-0.016-0.241-0.105-0.324L3.162,8.54L7.74,7.941c0.124-0.016,0.229-0.093,0.282-0.203L10,3.568l1.978,4.17c0.053,0.11,0.158,0.187,0.282,0.203l4.578,0.598L13.481,11.723z"></path></svg>
```